# I have a Dell Precision Tower 7910 with an Nvidia Quadro m2000. Won't show anything on monitor

Tags: windows, graphics-card, troubleshooting, nvidia-quadro

Computer: Dell Precision Tower 7910

GPU: Nvidia Quadro m2000

I am trying to use this computer, but I only have one monitor on hand that can hook up to it. I'm using a DP to HDMI cable from computer to monitor. I have verified the monitor works with VGA at least.

When I have it hooked up and I boot up, the screen turns on but it's pure black. Lights on the keyboard and mouse turn on. After a while, it just flickers between off and on to a solid black repeatedly. I don't even see the initial BIOS splash screen at the beginning but the monitor does turn on with a black screen.

However I just want to remote into this machine until I can a hand on another cable/monitor. I have never done any settings to this Dell machine whatsoever.

Is there a way I can remote into this based on its initial state out of the box? It's hooked up to the same switch/network as me right now and I cannot see it. I'd like to actually interface with this new computer if possible.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Remote access has to be authorized and configured first.

Comment: What graphics connections are available on the PC?  Are you plugging into port #1 on the m2000?  If no video on port #1 on the m2000 then the drivers for it haven't been loaded yet; you will need to plugin to the on-motherboard graphics for initial setup, then switch over to the nVidia after it has been installed properly.

Comment: There isn't on-board motherboard ports for any monitor input whatsoever. No VGA/DVI/HDMI/DP. I actually don't know why but it's frustrating. I will install another GPU/video card and try again. Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

One of your ram doesn't seat correctly or not match. Seat it accordingly, in orderly fashioned and secured. Clean the contact to make sure. After you have done all of these, your Dell (any Dell) will work find, resolved the "no display" for good.